# C# Is this circular dependency, is a good design (Data Access Layer with Filter Provider)?

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, database-design, entity-framework-core

Hi I'm learning a lot about design patterns and SOLID Principles, but right now I need to apply that knowledge to an app.

I'm working on a data access layer, it has CRUD methods, but I need to APPLY FILTERS based on certain conditions before running those methods against the database and here is my design, I think I have a circular dependency, and wanted some guidance or help how to keep it SOLID.

Note: Filters need to be dinamically stored and loaded somehow from some storage.

**IRepository.cs**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
  where TEntity : IEntity
  {
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Get(int id);
    //more actions ....
  }
```

**IFiltersProvider.cs**

```
  public interface IFiltersProvider
  {
    IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyFilters<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
      where TEntity : IEntity;
  }
```

**BaseRepository.cs**

```
  public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
   where TEntity : IEntity
  {
    protected IFiltersProvider filtersProvider;

    public void SetFiltersProvider(IFiltersProvider filtersProvider)
    {
      this.filtersProvider = filtersProvider;
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
      // Add to database without filters ....
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
      var query = ;//get here a IQueryable;
      filtersProvider?.ApplyFilters(query);

      return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
  }
```

Note: I have a **SetFiltersProvider** in this abstract class because not every repository will apply filters, I think I need a Interface for that.

Everything works if I have a InMemoryFiltersProvider.

Trying to provide filters from Database I believe here I'm breaking SOLID Principles, because I depend from a BaseRepository implementation.

**FilterRepository.cs**

```
public class FilterRepository : BaseRepository<Filter>, IRepository<Filter>
  {
  }
```

**DBFiltersProvider.cs**

```
public class DBFiltersProvider: IFiltersProvider
  {
    protected readonly FilterRepository filterRepository;

    public DBFiltersProvider(FilterRepository filterRepository)
    {
      filterRepository.SetFiltersProvider(this);
      this.filterRepository = filterRepository;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyFilters<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
      where TEntity : IEntity
    {
      var filters = filterRepository.GetFiltersByEntity<TEntity>();

      foreach (var filter in filters)
      {
        // logic to apply filter to query
      }

      return query;
    }
  }
```

Even when I'm working with interfaces I don't know if the Design it's clean, or circular dependecy problem.

Thanks so much.

Comment: *I think...*, *I believe...*, *some guidance*. Your question is very vague. Also it's not clear whether this is working code or not.

Comment: I haven't seen repositories being dependent on a filter like that before. I would consider keeping things simple. Skip the filter implementation. For the real generic part of the filter move that to extension methods of IQueryable.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm learning to speak english, so sorry for my imperfect English, if you read all, you'll see ITS WORKING but there is a CIRCULAR DEPENDECY

Comment: @FredrikRudberg Yeah extensions are good, but having filters provider within a separate class let me have many and different implementations ... Extensions aren't so flexible ....

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar problem a couple of years ago. I preferred to apply decorator pattern by using interception capabilities of [postsharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/apply-to-single-declaration).

This way you should redirect calls to a method having a filter parameter, then the interceptor is able to modify the filter, before pass it to the original method body.

It's declarative, so you can apply the interception only to desired repositories; so no probable circular dependency expected.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve hit a common problem with generic repositories. I’d call this a leaky abstraction because consumers of the repository need intimate knowledge of the datalayer to use filtering. Generic repositories just aren’t always the best solution. Consider implementing very specific search functions depending on what you really need like .FindOrdersForAccount. Or if you still need more flexibility a separate IqueryService with it’s own input and output models. My view is that generic repositories are god for some simple CRUD work, for more advanced use cases you want to be more expressive in your code.